# Software emulating a magnet-like schedule board

Tags: scheduling

I am looking for visual way to have a 48x7 rectangule and build 1x1-rectangular blocks to fill up the area with at least 9 different colors. There should be no possibility to overlap.

**Specific problem**
I have a physical magnetic board with a week-schedule divided in 49 rows and 8 columns. One row for each 30min of the day, one row for the names of the days, one column for the intervals of time and 7 columns for the days of the week. 
I also have 336(=48*7) rectangular magnets of the size of each field and they represent a variety of activities. I move this arround to organize, set, test and adapt schedules.

> Which software emulates this?

I am looking for this to run on Android and/or Linux(Debian) or as a web-app.